# Saving Coordinates and Depth in a File on click

Tags: qgis, raster, qgis-plugins

I am working on Hydrographic maps and I have used the interpolation plugin and got the depth at all points in a raster layer. Now I need to save the Lat\Long and depth in a text file. I am aware of the copy_coords plugin but it saves only x and y coordinates. Similar to copy_coords, I need a code/plugin which also copies (or saves) the depth.

Comment: Are you interested in getting x,y,depth for only selected points or all cells of your raster layer?

Comment: Only selected points

Answer (score 2):

Use [Point Sampling tool](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/pointsamplingtool/) to extract raster value (depth) to the selected points. But you need to save the selected points as a new shapefile.

Please note that point sampling tool works perfectly if the spatial references for both raster and points are same. If the points and raster data have different spatial references (different projections), the output will be point data with empty fields.

Comment: This gives me only depth. I also need x and y coordinates.

Comment: Save the X and Y coordinates in a text file and load the data using "Add delimited text layer", and save the file as shapefile. Then follow the explanation in my answer.